# не сохраняет SharedPreferences android

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Хочу сохранять результат игры в отдельный активити. Пытаюсь сохранять через SharedPreferences. B методе save() идет сохранение текста из editText'ов. В методе load() хочу реализовать возможность добавить в другое активити TextView и поставить сохраненные данные. Данные в другом активити почему-то не сохраняются.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnSave:
            save();
            load();
            break;
        case R.id.btnCancle:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}

private void save() {
    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(SAVE_FIRST_NAME, etFirstName.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(SAVE_LAST_NAME, etLastName.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(SAVE_POINT, etPoints.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(SAVE_TIME, etTime.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(SAVE_TRY, etTry.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(SaveScoreActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
void load() {
    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    TextView tvFirstName = new TextView(this);
    TextView tvLastName = new TextView(this);
    TextView tvPoints = new TextView(this);
    TextView tvTry = new TextView(this);
    TextView tvTime = new TextView(this);

    tvFirstName.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(SAVE_FIRST_NAME, "unnamed"));
    tvLastName.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(SAVE_LAST_NAME, "unnamed"));
    tvPoints.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(SAVE_POINT, "unnamed"));
    tvTry.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(SAVE_TRY, "unnamed"));
    tvTime.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(SAVE_TIME, "unnamed"));

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.addView(tvFirstName);
    layout.addView(tvLastName);
    layout.addView(tvPoints);
    layout.addView(tvTry);
    layout.addView(tvTime);

    ScoreActivity scoreActivity = new ScoreActivity();

    scoreActivity.layoutScore = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutScore);
    scoreActivity.layoutScore.addView(layout);
}
```

Comment: "ScoreActivity scoreActivity = new ScoreActivity();" - оу-оу, прежде почитайте про то как работать с Activity - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: @s_klepcha Через SharePreferences нельзя сохранить данные в другое активити?

Comment: вызов пустого конструктора активити ничего не даёт

Comment: @s_klepcha не могу понять, как записать данные в другое активити, не заходя в него

Comment: записывайте и загружайте данные из хранилища всего приложения, не из конкретного Activity.

Comment: @metalurgus Создал класс Синглтон и в него копирую ссылку preferenes. Потом из другого активити беру эту ссылку и сохраняю значения. Но почему-то оно не сохраняется

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно просто использовать

```
this.getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

В обеих `Activity` для того, чтобы они читали и записывали из/в одни и те же `SharedPreferences`